# Struts2 Action not invoked, but request reaches the server

Tags: struts2

We have a weird scenario in PROD.  Our registration form works fine generally but just for one user who is trying to register from mobile via browser, the registration request is sent to the server, I can see it httpd & tomcat access logs with 200 as status code, however, I could not see any evidence of Struts Action being invoked.  We log the evidence of action getting called in the first line of the method, but there is nothing in the log, so it is not invoked.  This is happening second time, for the same user.  We could not reproduce this either in PC or mobile, everything works just fine.  There is no error or anything in application log, catalina.out or catalina.log file.  The form is plain HTML form without struts tag and angularJS is used.  Is there any other place that we can look up for some hints on what is happening here?

One of the form elements is given below and remaining looks similar to this -

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2">Full name</label>
<div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control formfield" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="30"  name="user.fullname" size="30"  ng-model="user.fullname" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="4"  ng-maxlength="30" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-focus="errorName = ''></div>
```

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'register',              
data:  new FormData($("#regform")[0]),
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function(data) {

},        
error: function(data) {

}
```

});

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any validation running, or perhaps the conversion interceptor is adding a conversion error and therefore trying redirect to the "input" result.  If possible, override the validate() if you have not already done so and at the end of the method log the value of hasErrors().  this will tell you if something if something has added an action error.  If that is the case, you will need to further dig down into the actionErrors/fieldErrors to see what is happening

Comment: Thank you @PaulZepernick for your comments.  I edited my question and added some HTML & JS. I am using a plain HTML form with AngularJS validation.  When the form is successful, form is submitted through an AJAX request.  I am not using any interceptor in struts config and the action is also not implementing anything else other than SessionAware, ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware.  Is there still a possibility for conversion interceptor to be called?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the default interceptor stack.  You would need to check your struts config to see what interceptor stack you are using.

Comment: Is there anything coming back in your success() of your js callback?

Comment: Well, we could not check that because this happened just for one user when he tried to register from mobile via browser.   We could not reproduce it, either in mobile or PC.  May be the easiest way is to get in touch with the user and try to understand what data was submitted.  This will at least give some clue on how to reproduce in our DEV environment.  I am quite sure, that the form itself would not accept string in place of integer or something like that.  Thank you once again @PaulZepernick

Comment: Just wanted to share that we got in touch with the user and understood the user was trying to submit decimal in place of integer in the form.  Thank you @PaulZepernick for giving us the clue.